# Make [rails5] a synonym of [ruby-on-rails-5]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[rails5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails5) has 135 questions currently and with no tag info. It's an obvious synonym to [ruby-on-rails-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-5), which has 4500+ questions and more details.

[rails5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails5) is already suggested as a tag synonym for [ruby-on-rails-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-5), but I can't vote the suggestion up because I don't have enough reputation, so I though it'd be good to create a meta post for this.

Comment: That extra 5-rep rule seems... excessive. You and I both have the power to edit and close-vote anything we deem worthy regardless of what tags are present, but we can't vote on this open and shut case?

Comment: Handy link for those with enough reputation in the tag to vote for the synonym: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby-on-rails-5/synonyms

Comment: lol, I have enough to vote for all the other Rails related tags but not that one.

Answer (score 5):

I performed the merge/synonym creation via magic mod powers, since I don't think there's enough rep in this tag for the community to handle this one.

```
updating post history, 155 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 144 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 112 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 4786
tag remapping of [ruby-on-rails-5] and [rails5] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
15 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
9 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym rails5 -> ruby-on-rails-5 was approved!
```